# Insert a vector inside another vector without using the former vector's begin and end (C++20)?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdvector, c++20

Currently I am inserting a vector inside another like this:

```
#include <vector>

int main(const int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::vector<int> old_elements{1, 2, 3};

    std::vector<int> elements{4, 5, 6};
    elements.insert(elements.end(), old_elements.begin(), old_elements.end());
}
```

What I want to do is something like this

```
std::vector<int> get_old_elements()
{
    return std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3};
}

int main(const int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::vector<int> elements{4, 5, 6};
    elements.insert(elements.end(), get_old_elements());
}
```

So I cannot call begin and end without first storing the temporary result. Is there a way to get this done? During one of the cppcon talks on `ranges`, I heard it being said that it might be end of begin and end. So I guess there could be some way to achieve something like this with ranges library.

Comment: How about `elements = get_old_elements()`?

Comment: Updated the question to make it more clear what I intended to do

Comment: @yasht: Why is it so necessary to avoid storing a local object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
std::experimental::ranges::copy(get_old_elements(), std::back_inserter(elements));
```

But it would be more efficient to do this:

```
template <typename From, typename To>
void append(const From& from, To& to) {
    to.insert(std::begin(from), std::end(from), to.end());
}

append(get_old_elements(), elements);
```

This can reserve capacity for the new elements whereas back_inserter cannot.